# Можно ли и почему поставить запятую

Tags: пунктуация

> За­пряжённые в сохи и бо­ро­ны ло­ша­ди были сытые и круп­ные.

По составителю задания, запятая не нужна после причастного оборота. Однако ее хочется поставить из-за обстоятельственного значения

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна, т.к. здесь нет обстоятельственного значения, нельзя сказать: Будучи запряженными в сохи и бо­ро­ны(,) ло­ша­ди были сытые и круп­ные. Иначе получится, что лошади были сытыми и крупными, потому что были запряженными в сохи.

Хотя предложение тоже некорректное, в нем ошибка в построении однородных членов предложения, объединяются два несопоставимых понятия: сытые и крупные.

Comment: Интересную ошибку вы нашли, не заметил её.

Comment: Хотя это из ["Анны Карениной"](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1099/p.94/index.html).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Может, он хотел сказать, что крупные, потому что всегда сытые? То есть жирные от этого. Диссонанс прилагательных ощущается на слух. Так не следует делать, при всём уважении к Толстому.

Comment: @oleedd,мне тоже так кажется.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Видимо, приходит, только когда автор ответа отвечает.

Comment: Вроде бы у Розенталя даже есть правило.

Comment: @oleedd Понятно, что никто не застрахован от ошибок (а может, он что-то другое имел в виду под "сытыми", не знаю). Я просто дал информацию, откуда это предложение. //  Я ставлю "отслеживать", и любые сообщения доходят.

Comment: Какое правило? О построении разнородных ОЧ?

Comment: @Серж Вроде бы что-то было о том, что нельзя "и" соединять разнородные вещи.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Тоже ставлю, но когда подключается ещё один не автор, а не когда первым пишу комментарий.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Тогда язык был другим. Может, тогда было модно соединять неоднородное (изюминка).